# Vala GTK3 find child by name

Tags: gtk3, vala

Using Vala 0.30, how do you find a GTK child widget by name?

The main code calls a function to set up the application layout:

```
text.application_layout ();
```

The function creates the window and layout boxes.

```
class Example : Gtk.Window
  {
  public void application_layout ()
```

I want unrelated code to place content in some of the boxes. In C + GTK I could define the window as a global variable and any code could find a child box then add content. I cannot find a working equivalent in Vala.

Jen suggested using Container.get_children(). I will experiment with that. In the previous C code, the get_children approach produced thousands of children when a grid was populated.

Some Web pages show Vala classes with public strings. Vala will not compile the examples of a class when the public variable is a GTK widget. I also tried a dozen variations that work in other languages and fail in Vala.

Finally I found a way to have a public GTK widget that can be found by other code. The following compiles. All the online examples are slightly different and fail to compile in the current Vala.

```
class Example : Gtk.Window
  {
  public Grid example_grid = new Grid ();
  public void application_layout ()
```

If this is the only option, I will have to make many items public public.

I will still have the problem of finding the last child in a variable length set of children, something like the last label added to a box or the last row added to a grid. I would like to label items in a long list with a name like last then find it direct instead of reading through a thousand children every time.

Another update. The following grid definition works from within the class. It works from other methods of the class when called within the class.

```
class Example : Gtk.Window
  {
  public Grid example_grid;

  this.directory_grid = new Grid ();
```

My main code has var example = new Example(); and passes the example object to other code that needs user interface elements. The other code can then access example.example_grid or a method that updates example.grid. This means changing the other code to accept the example object.

I found then lost a page showing how you can access the main window object without having the object passed to the function. If I can find that again, it would let me access example.example_grid without having to change the code to pass the example object. This is getting close to a solution.

Comment: Something like `Container.get_children ()`? http://valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Container.get_children

Comment: Your question is quite confusing, you are asking for at least two different things here (How to get container children, how to get widgets by name, how to save widgets in variables, how to make things public, ...). You should split it to multiple questions, if necessary.

Comment: @Jens, the part about making things public was meant to read as "if there is no find by name, how do you let other code find the widget". I will try rewording the question.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to contain a MCVE? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: As for the getting the last inserted child problem: Why don't you just store the last inserted child in a variable (or dictionary or similar container)? I suspect that your problems are not with the Vala language, but conceptual problems. A MCVE would really help.